# How full is iPhone voicemail box?

Tags: iphone, voicemail

On an iPhone, how can I find out how full my voicemail box is? I'm not talking about how much space voicemail is taking up on my phone's storage. I believe each cell provider sets some limit of how much space your voicemails can take up until people won't be able to leave you voicemail. How do I find out how close I am to that limit? Is there any indication on the phone when it's full?

Comment: First Ask Different works best with one question per post, you may want to edit it. Also you already answered your own (first) question. Your provider sets the number of or size of your voicemail boxes. Dial 611 from your cell phone and ask a CS rep what that number is.

Comment: Moved the other question to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/319957/20799. And if you think your answer is correct for the first question, you can put it as an answer so people can upvote.